# Why is Open Sans changing "eh" to "P" in Safari?

Tags: html, safari, google-font-api, text-rendering

This is a weird quirk!

I have a website using Open Sans as the body font, and when viewed in Safari, any instance of lowercase “eh” in the text is rendered in the browser as an uppercase “P”.

*e.g.* “rehearsal” becomes “rPearsal”

I’m only seeing this in Safari, not Chrome or Firefox (Macbook Pro running macOS Sierra)

When viewing with Inspect Element, the markup is correct, it's only rendering like this on the front end… I’ve tried googling for solutions, but I can’t find anything on this bug… any ideas?

Comment: Add a working example

Comment: Has to be something else - link to the page in question, please, or create an example either here via a snippet, or on jsfiddle or similar. Specific JS for Safari only? Something else quirky going on? Probably not the font itself, since it works in Chrome and FF (same engine on Chrome and Safari).